# How to construct a maximum sum path linked list out of 2 sorted linked lists?

Tags: c++

I am trying to return a sorted linked list that has the maximum sum path out of 2 already sorted linked lists.
The function is listed below: It takes two started lists as parameters.

I am always prompted with the Segmentation Fault error.

```c
List MaxSumPath(List l1, List l2)  {

    List l3;
    Node* temp1 = l1.head;
    Node* temp2 = l2.head;

    Node* path1 = temp1;
    Node* path2 = temp2;

    while(temp1 != 0 || temp2 != 0) {


        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;

        while (temp1 != 0 && temp2 != 0 && temp1->data != temp2->data) {

            sum1 += temp1->data;
            path1->next = temp1;
            temp1 = temp1->next;

            sum2 += temp2->data;
            path2->next = temp2;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }

        if (sum1 > sum2) {
            while (path1 != 0) {
                l3.AddToTail(path1->data);
                path1 = path1->next;
            }
        } else {
            while (path2 != 0) {
                l3.AddToTail(path2->data);
                path2 = path2->next;
            }
        }

        if (temp1 == 0) {
            while (temp2 != 0) {
                l3.AddToTail(temp2->data);
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
        }

        if (temp2 == 0) {
            while (temp1 != 0) {
                l3.AddToTail(temp1->data);
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return l3;
}
```

I expect l3 to hold the resultant linked list.

[Full Source Code](http://pastebin.com/kTDXK9xe)

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes when they happens, and use it to locate where in your code it happens and then examine the values of the involved variables.

Comment: A hint though: When and where do you allocate memory for `path1` or `path2`?

Comment: I see no reason here to use raw pointers. C++ has a extremely powerful feature called RAII. Just do `Node path1`.

Comment: You can use [`std::set_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) to get the sorted union of two sets.

Comment: @ some-programmer-dude Sorry but I don't have time to learn it now, the due is after 2 hours.

Comment: The code in your link has `using namespace std` and uses _data_ and _next_ as variable names, while there is also std::data and std::next. This is ungood.

Comment: @nada Unfortunately, I am forced to solve this manually.

Comment: @SamanthaRocker If you have to use raw pointers, then, I am afraid, you have to take time and learn how to use them. We all had to. One hint:: You have to do things like `Node* path1 = new Node()`, or else path1 is just an uninitialized pointer, which segfaults on dereference.

Comment: @SamanthaRocker I am sorry that you are running out of time, but people here is busy too to go and debug your code. Anyway, I think one possible explanation is that you declare pointers to Node, but not allocate memory (as @Someprogrammerdude already hinted.

Pointers point to memory addresses, but if you don't reserve that space first hand, they will point nowhere. So when you do `path1->next = temp1;` there is no `next` or `data` members there.

Comment: @SamanthaRocker I would also recommend you to initialise pointers with `nullptr` as it is safer when dealing with raw pointers. [Description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)

Comment: The first thing is to make sure you don't have a faulty list before using it to actually solve problems.  You wouldn't use a broken hammer to hammer a nail in the wall, right?  The `List` class is very faulty.  If you added a destructor to clean up the list (which it should have anyway), the whole `List` falls apart due to the return of a `List` by value.  Is this how they're teaching proper C++?